# Operator weirdness with plus and minus

Tags: c++, operators

So, I was learning about the operators, and in particular, about binary operators.

In the following code:

```
int x=9;
x=-x;
cout<<x; // prints as -9

x=+x;

cout<<x; //prints as -9
```

the question is why not as 9 or +9(contextual) than -9 ? why it works like this ?

Comment: Because in `-x` can be thought as `0-x`. And `+x` as `0+x`.

Comment: ah , so thats how it works ? i meant thats how the compiler sees it ?

Comment: what else did you expect? Usually it is difficult to draw parallels to maths notation, but here it is the same `+x` is just `x` and `-x` is `x` negated

Comment: That's how it works in math. `-` is negation, that is a complement to zero. `+` is pretty much nothing other than emphasis of the positive sign. Another way to think about is is `-x = (-1)*x`, `+x = (+1)*x`

Comment: To be clear - you expected `+ ( -x )` to yield `x`?

Comment: hint: if x is -9 then why does x=-x make it 9 again instead of making it still -9?

Answer (score 3):

`x=-x;` means assign to `x` value which is negative to current `x`.

`x=+x;` means assign to `x` value which is promoted to type `int` which is already an `int`. Since in this step `x` already has value `-9` from previous operation nothing is changed and again `-9` is printed.

Here are [some docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Unary_arithmetic_operators).

Comment: but still int x=+(-6); prints as -6

Comment: @JohnMellow [Unary arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Unary_arithmetic_operators)

Comment: @JohnMellow OTOH `-(-6)` will print `6`. As you would expect in math. This is really not C++ or programming specific notation.

Comment: @JohnMellow I'm not sure why you are confused. Maybe you think those are mathematical expressions not assignments to variable?

Comment: @JohnMellow `+x` is the same as `x` in the case of numeric types. Look at it this way : `+x` is basically `+1 * x` where is `-x` is basically `-1 * x`. `+x` does not mean "`x` but positive".

Comment: `short x = -6;` and then `x = +x;` is the same as `x = static_cast<int>(x);` to make it a bit more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

`x=-x`, or to make it more readable `x = -x`, is basically operation of reversing the sign of `x`.

`x = +x`, is a trivial operation, since it copies `x` into `x`, since in previous operation the sign was reversed,`x` is `-9`, so now `-9` is copied into `x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x=9;
x=-x; //What is this for ? you mean x = x - 1 ? In this case syntax should be  x -= x same for + expression.
cout<<x; // prints as -9
x=+x;
cout<<x; //prints as -9
```

If above expressions are correct, but you're asking about -9 as end answer here is solution.

> line 1: init x with 9.

> line 2: assigned x with -(minus) of x which is -9

> line 4: assigned x with +(plus) of x which is +(-9) equals -9

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple math problem. minus times a plus is a minus hence , a plus times a minus is still a minus. This is the easiest way to look at it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).